# programmatic creation of jupyter 4 notebooks?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to programmatically generate some `*.ipnb` as part of my modeling work, so that i can dump annotated figures and code with markdown annotation to a public git repo. Ideally, I will create a new notebook and publish it every time I run new models.

from [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/fperez/9716279) gist, i found a pattern for doing this that involves: `from IPython.nbformat import current as nbf`

However, `IPython.nbformat.current` has been deprecated since last spring, and in fact is not present in jupyter/ipython 4.0.1, so this won't work for me.

What's the right pattern for this now?

Answer (score 6):

D'oh.

`IPython.nbformat` is deprecated.

`nbformat` is not...

this seems to work just fine:

```
from nbformat import current as nbf


def make_notebook(outPath: str, description: str):
    nb = nbf.new_notebook()
    code = "1+2"
    cells = [nbf.new_text_cell('markdown', description), nbf.new_code_cell(code)]
    nb['worksheets'].append(nbf.new_worksheet(cells=cells))

    fname = 'test.ipynb'

    with open(path.join(outPath,fname), 'w') as _:
        nbf.write(nb, _, 'ipynb')
```

Comment: It seems that `nbformat.current` is deprecated too. One can check here the latest API: https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 2):

an updated version for v4

there are probably better versions, this worked for me.

```py
from nbformat import v4 as nbf
import nbformat
from os import path



def make_notebook(outPath: str, description: str):
    nb = nbf.new_notebook()
    code = "1+2"
    cells = [nbf.new_markdown_cell( description), nbf.new_code_cell(code)]
    nb['cells'] = cells

    fname = 'test.ipynb'
    print(nb)
    with open(path.join(outPath,fname), 'w') as _:
        nbformat.write(nb, _)
```